# Not showing old migrated content in website

Tags: wp-config

I have migrated my database from one server to another, and configured my new database details.

Now, WordPress is not showing any old content in my new site - it is only showing my newly inserted content.

What extra configuration should be done to show all the content in the site?

Comment: It sounds like you _haven't_ migrated your database across, if none of your old content is there. How did you migrate the database?

Comment: Is your database table prefixes the same as whats in your wp-config.php?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the paths in Database and config files properly ?

Could you please proceed the below checklist for find the issues:

1. Back Up Your Website’s Files
2. Export The WordPress Database (using wp-migrate db plugin avoid some conflict )
   refernce url : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/
3. Create The WordPress Database On Your New Host Server and import the DB
4. Edit the wp-config.php File ( Change The Database Name, Username and Password)

5.Upload The WordPress Files To Your New Host

Comment: In same database I have two types of tables with wp and wp_ prefix  all parameters are correct . newly installed in wp that is working not i tried wp_ then it in not showing any thing??

Comment: I have jus downloaded the database from my old server i didnt use ant tool to take backup